# Determine if the polynomial $X^4+2X^2+1 \in \Bbb Z_3[X]$ is non divisible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

> Determine if the polynomial $X^4+2X^2+1 \in \Bbb Z_3[X]$ is non divisible.

I couldn’t find any theorems on ”non divisiblity” so I assume that this isn’t divisible since it doesn’t have any roots in $\Bbb Z_3$? We have that $0+0+1=1, 1+2+1=4=1$ and $2^4+8+1=25=1$. Wouldn’t this imply that the polynomial doesn’t factor and thus doesn’t have any divisor?

Comment: If by "non-divisible" you mean irreducible, then it is not sufficient to show there are no roots in $\Bbb Z_3$ since it might factorise as two quadratic polynomials.

Comment: $u^2 + 2u+ 1 = (u+1)^2$. Put $u = x^2$ to see that the given polynomial is redicible.

Comment: The polynomial is obviously a square in $\Bbb Z_3[X]$, hence reducible. More precisely, it is $(x^2+1)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over any field you have $X^4+2X^2+1=(X^2+1)^2$, and therefore $X^4+2X^2+1$ is reducible, even when it has no roots. It's only when the degree of polynomial is $2$ or $3$ that the non-existence of roots implies that the polynomial is irreducible.